# DJANGO: How to write a custom serializer that add a field from a related model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    db = 'default'
    subjectName = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cohortID = models.ForeignKey(Cohort, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects')
    teacherID = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects', null=True)

class Cohort(models.Model):
    db = 'default'
    school_creator = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='cohorts')
    mainTeacherID = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='mainCohorts')
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Serializer:

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Subject
        fields = ('subjectName', 'teacherID', 'pk',)
```

This is a response using serializer above:

```
{"subjectName":"Maths","teacherID":2,"pk":4}
```

I would like to have:

```
{"subjectName":"Maths","teacherID":2,"pk":4, "cohortName" : "4 B"}
```

cohortName should be taken from model Cohort.class_name.
I guess it is possible to do that because Subject is connect to Cohort by ForeignKey Subject.cohortID.
I have tried to add some custom Serializer:

```
class SubjectCohortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cohortName = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Subject
        fields = ('subjectName', 'teacherID', 'pk','cohortName')
    def get_cohortName(self, subject):
        return models.Cohort.objects.get(pk=self.context['request'].cohortID.className)
```

But surely I am doing something wrong, and it is really difficult to grasp what is happening in a serializer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **`get_cohortName()`** method to,

```
class SubjectCohortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cohortName = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Subject
        fields = ('subjectName', 'teacherID', 'pk', 'cohortName')

    def get_cohortName(self, subject):
        return subject.cohortID.className
```

Comment: Woow, Thank you so much, I was close to kill myself, appreciated